# How to use pattern with variables in awk

Tags: awk

My file is as below; I want to display those records of students whose percentage is above 80.

```
Studid    StudName     Asp.Net   DBMS     Unix
   1       Ani         75        62       80
   2       George      90        95       82
   3       Jake        45        30       40
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
```

so I used following code:

```
awk '(($3+$4+$5)/3)>80 {print}' stud
```

It works, but I want to assign these columns into variable and then want to display output. 
So I tried below code, but it didn't work

```
awk 'total=$3+$4+$5, per=total/3, per>80 {print}' stud
```

any solution with variables?

Comment: not sure why you need to assign them into variable.. `awk 'NR==1 || ($3+$4+$5)/3 > 80' stud` looks simple and easy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the logic from the *rule* section into an *action*

```
awk '{total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3; if (per>80) print}' stud
   2       George      90        95       82
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
```

Note that this attempts to evaluate the column headers arithmetically - which "works" because in `awk`, non-numeric fields are treated as zero when you try to do arithmetic on them - but would cause the header line to be printed if, for example, you changed the test to `per<80`. Better IMHO would be to either explicitly skip the header line using a `next` action for the rule `NR==1`

```
awk 'NR==1 {next} {total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3; if (per>80) print}' stud
   2       George      90        95       82
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
```

or, if you want the header, explicitly print it

```
awk 'NR==1 {print; next} {total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3; if (per>80) print}' stud
Studid    StudName     Asp.Net   DBMS     Unix
   2       George      90        95       82
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
```

Comment: will you please specify the meaning of {print;next} statement. Actually i want to skip first line in some queries so i wrote NR>1 but it didn't work.

Comment: @Dip please see updated answer

Comment: You can also do some code golfing and say `{total=$3+$4+$5; per=total/3} (per>80)`. That last part will trigger the print if it evaluates to True.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
awk ' 
# if /^Studid/ is matched move to the next record (row) of the input text
/^Studid/ { next }
{               
    total=$3+$4+$5
    per=total/3
    if (per > 80)  
        print 
}' stud
```

output

```
   2       George      90        95       82
   4       Dennie      89        92       90
```